# How to do a certain feature in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i wasn't sure how to word this correctly so this question might already exist.
I came up with an idea that I could do in python and decided to do it in Notepad++,
Looking at a discord bot template that I had downloaded I noticed these (Not the correct term but it's the best way I could describe them) Toggle blocks, where if you pressed on the +/- it would hide / show the section of code. I'm just wondering how I can do this.

All help is appreciated and i'm sorry if this question already exists, if you could go one step further and tell me what it's actually called it would be much appreciated.

[An example of what I am talking about:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VQYH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's referred to as "Folding" and you can do this by going to *Language - Define your language* and then setting what symbols you want to use.